# Display command prompt (PS1) info for a set of directories

Tags: bash, shell-script, git, prompt

**Is there a straightforward way to display the results of my `PS1` for a given set of directories?**

To avoid the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/235513), I'll state up front: I want to rapidly check the status of every git repo within a directory. I can run `git status` in a `for ... do ... done` loop, but that is hard to read.

I have [oh-my-git](https://github.com/arialdomartini/oh-my-git) running beautifully as part of my command prompt and it displays the status I'd like to know at a glance. I'd like to see what it says for every sub-directory in my `repos` directory.

I can see what I need by manually calling `cd ~/repos/first-repo` followed by the next, but besides the repetitive typing, I also have to remember all of the repos without skipping one. I'd be happy to script out `cd`ing into each repo and displaying my customized prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for rep in */; do
    printf '%s:\t' "$rep"
    ( cd "$rep" && git status --short --branch --untracked-files=no )
done
```

or, using short options,

```
for rep in */; do
    printf '%s:\t' "$rep"
    ( cd "$rep" && git status -sbuno )
done
```

This changes into each directory in the current directory and runs the given `git status` command.  The output may look something like

```
gnomad_browser/:        ## master...origin/master
swefreq-browser/:       ## gnomad-remerge...origin/gnomad-remerge
swefreq-config/:        ## develop...origin/develop
swefreq/:       ## feature/schema-update...origin/feature/schema-update
 M sql/swefreq.sql
```

(I have an uncommitted file in the `swefreq` repository)

The options picked for `git status` here will show just the current branch and any modified files, but you could easily modify it to show untracked files as wull by removing `-uno` or `--untracked-files=no`.

See `git status --help`.

---

Your idea of using the prompt to show you info about each directory may work depending on how your prompt is set up.  My prompt is a single-quoted string that must be evaluated:

```
for rep in */; do
    ( cd "$rep" && eval echo "$PS1" )
done
```

I do not think that this is a very nice solution, and it's also not very flexible in what it can do and tell you about each repository.

Comment: `eval` is something I wasn't thinking of, and seems to be what I'd like to use, but it chokes on my complex `PS1`. It's probably the font-awesome icons included, which is the point.

Comment: I'm glad I included my XY problem clarification because your solution provides 90% of the value I was looking for. I'm changing the string formatting to `printf '%-28s' "$rep"` for myself, but that's pretty nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at oh-my-git, it seems to need you to do something like this in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.oh-my-git/prompt.sh
for d in dir1 dir2...
do cd "$d"
   pwd
   bash_prompt      # recalculate PS1 value
   echo -en "$PS1"
done
```

Comment: Here's what I get when I try `echo -en "$PS1"`: https://imagebin.ca/v/3bddQYqoj7Ik

Comment: I'm using the usual gnu echo command with option `-e` which interprets `\e` as the escape character. For example, `echo -en '\e'|od -c` yields octal code 033. Perhaps you have another echo command earlier in your PATH?  If you cannot find a  suitable echo you might try `printf "$PS1"`, as it should interpret the `\e` when in the format arg, though if you have any `%` in the string that would be awkward, and you would need `printf "${PS1//%/%%}"`.